# Why is my file not being loaded?

Tags: php, ajax, html, forms, upload

I am simply trying to upload a file and nothing is working.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html><body>

            <form id="exp" enctype = "multipart/form-data" action="../cgi-bin/uploadPic.php">
                <input type="file" id="profilePic2" name="newPic"></input> <br /><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" value="Upload Pic" style="color:black;"></input>
            </form>
  </body></html>
```

My php file is being executed. Please mind the sloppy code, I am trying to debug via echo.

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <?php

$loadFile = true; // error code
$allowedExts = array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["newPic"]["name"]));

$file = $_FILES["newPic"];
$picIncluded = false;

if((    ($_FILES["newPic"]["type"] == "image/gif")
||  ($_FILES["newPic"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
||  ($_FILES["newPic"]["type"] == "image/png")
||  ($_FILES["newPic"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&&  ($_FILES["newPic"]["size"] < 5000000)
&&  in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
    if($_FILES["newPic"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "pnl"; // error code returned to client
    }
    else if(file_exists("../profile-pics/" . $file["name"])){
        echo "pld"; // picture loaded duplicate
    } else {
        $picIncluded = true;
        echo "finally";
        if(move_uploaded_file($file["name"]["tmp_name"],"./" . $file["name"])){
            echo "Success again!";
        }
        $path = "../profile-pics/" . $file["name"];
    }
}
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["newPic"]["name"]["tmp_name"])){
    echo "Good news!";
}

 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Anyway, the function move_uploaded_file() is returning false since it can't find the temp file. is_uploaded_file() is also return false. My extensions and everything is correct but still to no avail, there is no file being uploaded. How can I debug this?

Comment: Have you had enough folder permissions?

Comment: How do I check? I'm using Fedora. My php is in /var/www/cgi-bin/. Where would temp files be written to?

Comment: oops. No idea about Fedora. Someone may help you.

Comment: I also found that when you check for file you used this directory `../profile-pics/` but when uploading the file you not used it...

Comment: I'm simply debugging. I'm just seeing if I saved it. This code is part of a much bigger script.

Comment: @edwin, you had the answer. I had to tell selinux to allow read/write file access to apache. I don't have much Systems Administrations experience so I"m learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this

```
if(move_uploaded_file($file["name"]["tmp_name"],"./" . $file["name"])){
```

to

```
if(move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"],"./" . $file["name"])){
```

because you have assigned

```
$file = $_FILES["newPic"];
```

Comment: I don't think this is the reason.

Comment: @Mr.Student Once you assigned `$file = $_FILES["newPic"];` , you can only refer single dimensional array of $file, there is no two dimensional array in $file.

Answer (score 2):

Also for security check, you must check for is_uploaded_file() before uploading:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["newPic"]["tmp_name"])){
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["newPic"]["tmp_name"],"../profile-pics/" . $file["name"])){
  echo 'file uploaded...';
 }
}else{
  echo "Possible file upload attack: ";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I didn't know about that and I am always up to learning best practices.